# Auth0 getting powerBI token

Tags: azure-active-directory, auth0

I am authentocating using Auth0 and my provider is `wadd`

[image]

I am trying to get the token to use with PowerBi, I have tried the follow console app (token, is from the above, clientId and Secret are the same as what is used in my Auth0 connector for the connection to my `AzureAD`

```
        var cred = new ClientCredential(clientId, secret);

        var access_token_from_client_side = token;
        var context = new AuthenticationContext("https://login.windows.net/common");

        var res = context.AcquireTokenAsync("https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api",
        functionCred, new UserAssertion(access_token_from_client_side)).ConfigureAwait(false).GetAwaiter().GetResult();

        Console.WriteLine(res.AccessToken);
```

I get the following error

```
{"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"AADSTS50013: Assertion failed signature validation. [Reason - The provided signature value did not match the expected signature value., Thumbprint of key used by client: '...', Found key 'Start=12/26/2019 00:00:00, End=12/25/2024 00:00:00']\r\nTrace ID: ...\r\nCorrelation ID: ...\r\nTimestamp: 2020-02-25 21:13:48Z","error_codes":[50013],"timestamp":"2020-02-25 21:13:48Z","trace_id":"...","correlation_id":"b890dfad-1d6f-4e4a-ab15-34328818c295","error_uri":"https://login.microsoftonline.com/error?code=50013"}
```

My goal is to get a Token to use for PowerBI starting with my AzureAD auth token. I have allow the application permissions for PowerBI from Azure

What am I missing?

Comment: Why don't you use `var res=context.AcquireTokenAsync("https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api", cred );` to get the token?

Comment: @TonyJu thanks for the suggestion, that does give me a PowerBI token but it has no users and we don't have an embedded lic so it does not like it.

I have done a bit more work on this, this issue is Auth0, the Token that auth0 gives me as the login token is actualy the token for the GraphAPI. So the above code is never going to work.

However it does work if the initial token is correct, eg the one that  you get when y you first login.

Comment: I think you can add an answer. https://blogs.aaddevsup.xyz/2019/08/understanding-azure-ads-on-behalf-of-flow-aka-obo-flow/